# Splitting sentence into groups using Regexp

Tags: regex

```
<i>Location     Status     Alarm           Plug-In    Time

RST2         Set CR     Link to RST1                  4/12/94 08:14:22
LET 1 11     Set MJ     LOS OP            T1X-XCVR      4/10/94 10:17:45</i>
```

For the above messages

I wanted to split the above messages using regexp into groups,

I am trying this,

```
<i>(.*)\s+(Set|Clr|Cur)\s+([A-Z]+)\s+(.*)\s+(\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)</i>
```

and the output is 
For the first line

```
1.  [0-12]  `RST2        `   --          should not have whitespaces ( should be only "RST2")
2.  [13-16] `Set`
3.  [17-19] `CR`
4.  [24-50] `Link to RST1        GHT         `  -- should contain only "Link to RST1" GHT should be in another group
5.  [51-67] `4/12/94 08:14:22`
```

second line

```
1.  [0-12]  `LET 1 11    `  --   should not have trailing whitespaces ( should be only "LET 1 11")
2.  [13-16] `Set`
3.  [17-19] `MJ`
4.  [24-50] `LOS OP          T1X-XCVR  `   ----   This group should have only "LOS OP" without any whitespace and T1X-XCVR should be in another group
5.  [51-67] `4/10/94 10:17:45`
```

Is there any way to get my desired output.I tried +$ to remove whitespaces, but it doesnot work

Desired output

```
    1.  [0-12]  `RST2` 
    2.  [13-16] `Set`
    3.  [17-19] `CR`
    4.  [24-50] `Link to RST1`
    5.  [frm-to] ``
    6.  [51-67] `4/12/94 08:14:22`


    1.  [0-12]  `LET 1 11`
    2.  [13-16] `Set`
    3.  [17-19] `MJ`
    4.  [24-50] `LOS OP`
    5.  [frm-to] `T1X-XCVR`
    6.  [51-67] `4/10/94 10:17:45`</i>
```

Comment: This looks like a tab-delimited set. Why not just split on tabs?

Comment: Its not tab delimited, there could be as many whitespaces

Comment: "Is there any way to get my desired output" - Post an example of the desired output, also, what programming language are you using ?

Comment: I already added comments for my desired output, ok i will edit the question

Comment: When asking, you should always specify the language you're using because the regex syntax may change.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is lazy instead of greedy consumption.
`^(.*?)\s+(Set|Clr|Cur)\s+([A-Z]+)\s+(\w+(?: \w+)*)\s+(.*?)\s+(\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)(?:<\/i>)?$` works for your two input lines ([see it here](https://regex101.com/r/eL9vL8/1)). But it might fail on other input, for example when the "Plugin" string is only one space away from the one for "Alarm". In that case you cannot properly distinguish group 4 and 5 and need a proper delimiter or fixed column lengths.

Or, if you're reading out a website, check if the DOM is dynamically built from a JSON resource and if that is the case, try to fetch that resource directly.